# Ruby on Rails: Where Only Catches First Match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Where finds first match and displays it, but doesn't display anything after that. How can I change this to find and display all matches? Not just the first found result.

Example: Finds and displays coupon 'test1', but doesn't collect 'test2' or 'test3' coupons from a search of 'test'.

```
def self.note_search(params)
    matches = Coupon.all

    params.each do |key, val|

      case key
        when 'from'
          if val.present? && params[:to].present?
            from = Time.parse(params[:from]).beginning_of_day
            to = Time.parse(params[:to]).end_of_day
            matches.where!(created_at: from..to)
          end

        when 'coupon'
          if val.present?
            val.split(' ').each do |t|
              t = "%#{t.downcase}%"
              matches.where!("lower(title) LIKE ? or lower(coupon) LIKE ?", t, t )
            end
          end

      end

    end
    matches
  end
```

Desired result: Return full list of results based on search criteria, not just the first find.

Comment: Did you try using **select!**

Comment: Want to refactor that thing? https://mkdev.me/en/posts/how-to-use-query-objects-to-refactor-rails-sql-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting only one value because iterator returns result of last iteration. Should be:

```
when 'promo_code'
  return unless val.present?

  query = val.split(' ').map { |term| "%#{term.downcase}%" }
  matches.where("LOWER(title) LIKE ANY(ARRAY[?]) OR LOWER(coupon) LIKE ANY(ARRAY[?])", query, query)
end
```